# Use pandas to determine number of times a column has lowest value for a particular group

Tags: python, pandas

```
       Experiment  Source    RMSE
0    Experiment 10   sat8   931.453756
1    Experiment 10   sat8   861.855506
2    Experiment 10   sat8   859.305796
3    Experiment 10   sat8   655.863104
4    Experiment 10   sat8   935.915268
..            ...         ...          ...
571  Experiment 27  nel1   807.975352
572  Experiment 27  nel1  1146.975889
573  Experiment 27  nel1  1005.450225
574  Experiment 27  nel1   967.833854
575  Experiment 27  nel1   793.703938
```

I want to process the dataframe above to find the number of times a `Source` has the least `RMSE` value for a given `Experiment`. Result should look something like this:
For any given `Experiment`, only one of the `Source` can have the least RMSE so any given column sums up to 1.

```
sat8    0                        0 
nel1    1                        1
    Experiment 10 ....      Experiment 27
```

I tried using pivot table but not sure how to determine the `Source` with least `RMSE` for a given `Experiment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for minimal index (`Source`)  per groups by `RMSE` column:

```
df2 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Source')
                        .groupby('Experiment')['RMSE']
                        .idxmin()
         ).T

         )
print (df2)
Experiment  Experiment 10  Experiment 27
nel1                    0              1
sat8                    1              0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.set_index('Source').groupby('Experiment')['RMSE'].idxmin())
Experiment
Experiment 10    sat8
Experiment 27    nel1
Name: RMSE, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, somehow this is not working on my full dataset, will investigate and update.

Comment: I am getting 1's in all rows and columns

Comment: @user308827 - one thing, do you need second solution? Or first by count?

Comment: either is fine for me, although sameleast value of RMSE in multiple rows is unlikely to occur.

Comment: @user308827 - Maybe not first time understand question well, can you test now?